# java.lang.AbstractMethodError occurs during version ugrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, abstractmethoderror

I am trying to upgrade the versions of Spring from `4.1.7.RELEASE` to `5.2.6.RELEASE`, Hibernate from `4.3.5` to `5.4.17` and spring-boot from `1.2.5` to `2.2.7`.

Now i am facing a compile time error and facing a difficulty to troubleshoot the issue.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer' parameter 0; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2.RELEASE</version>    
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You are managing too many versions yourself, you should let spring boot manage those. You are using incompatible versions of frameworks.

Comment: what may be the real cause of this AbstractMethodError?How can i check the version compactibility?

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml`.